# Magento module have links with index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

magento module installed: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/news-by-commercelab.html

I installed the extension and everything works.
https://fafaconcepts.com/blog/ - here you can see it.

However there is a small problem with links.
If you click on test article (http://fafaconcepts.com/blog/test.html)
actually it goes to https://fafaconcepts.com/index.php/blog/test.html

Any idea what's wrong with that?

I also have the same extension on another shop without having the same problem.

Comment: it force you to secure url. add https on https://fafaconcepts.com/blog/test.html then it works

Comment: The site don't use SSL normally. Any idea how to make this module to not use SSL?